# MobileExpressCheckoutLibrary deprecated and not being in the US

Tags: ios, paypal, express-checkout

I've been trying to accept credit cards in my iOS App (not a mobile website, but a native app) using MPL but I realised simplePayment doesn't support credit card payments.

Being in England, I can't use the new iOS SDK. But MECL (mobile express checkout library) is also deprecated. I've seen that MEC (Mobile Express Checkout) is available, but there is no documentation available and I'm not sure if that's going to work for me.

What alternatives have I got?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with PayPal, it looks like you don't have any options:  you have to keep using MPL.

According to this in the first couple paragraphs of https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

> PayPal is replacing the Mobile Payments Libraries (MPL) with the
>   PayPal iOS SDK. The PayPal iOS SDK is currently available in the US,
>   with more country support coming soon. US developers should upgrade
>   now for more features and a better mobile experience. Non-US
>   developers, you can continue to use MPL for the time being.

I would suggest e-mailing or contacting PayPal to tell them to allow U.K. and/or Europeans in on the fun of the new iOS SDK a.s.a.p.

Or that you'll be considering making a permanent to a different payment processor (e.g. [Dwolla](http://blog.dwolla.com/introducing-our-new-mobile-sdks/) or [who knows what else](http://lifehacker.com/5821634/why-you-should-ditch-paypal-and-use-these-other-services-to-send-people-money)?).

Comment: Is there anyway I can use the deprecated MECL? Like putting it inside a web view? We need to deliver it to the client quite soon so can't really wait for Paypal to make the SDK available in the UK.

Comment: I see [PayPal documentation for MEC](http://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MEC/), so there's that an an option.